# Vectorization of weighted outer product

Tags: c++, vectorization, eigen

I am looking to accelerate the calculation of an approximate weighted covariance.

Specifically, I have a `Eigen::VectorXd(N) w` and a `Eigen::MatrixXd(M,N) points`. I'd like to calculate the sum of `w(i)*points.col(i)*(points.col(i).transpose())`.

I am using a for loop but would like to see if I can go faster:

```cpp
Eigen::VectorXd w = Eigen::VectorXd(N) ;
Eigen::MatrixXd points = Eigen::MatrixXd(M,N) ;
Eigen::MatrixXd tempMatrix = Eigen::MatrixXd(M,M) ;
for (int i=0; i < N ; i++){
    tempMatrix += w(i)*points.col(i)*(points.col(i).transpose());
}
```

Looking forward to see what can be done!

Comment: Two things springs to mind. `alignas` and `std::execution::par`. That is, align data to avoid false sharing using `std::hardware_destructive_interference_size`. Then use the standard library to process your data using the execution policy `std::execution::par`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd tempMatrix; // not necessary to pre-allocate
// assigning the product allocates tempMatrix if needed
// noalias() tells Eigen that no factor on the right aliases with tempMatrix
tempMatrix.noalias() = points * w.asDiagonal() * points.adjoint();
```

or directly:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd tempMatrix = points * w.asDiagonal() * points.adjoint();
```

If `M` is really big, it can be significantly faster to just compute one side and copy it (if needed):

```
Eigen::MatrixXd tempMatrix(M,M);
tempMatrix.triangularView<Eigen::Upper>() = points * w.asDiagonal() * points.adjoint();
tempMatrix.triangularView<Eigen::StrictlyLower>() = tempMatrix.adjoint();
```

Note that `.adjoint()` is equivalent to `.transpose()` for non-complex scalars, but with the former the code works as well if `points` and the result where `MatrixXcd` instead (`w` must still be real, if the result must be self-adjoint).

Also, notice that the following (from your original code) does not set all entries to zero:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd tempMatrix = Eigen::MatrixXd(M,M);
```

If you want this, you need to write:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd tempMatrix = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(M,M);
```

Comment: @RHertel They are equivalent for non-complex values. I like to write `.adjoint()` when it would be required for complexes for consistency (or in case I actually need to make the code generic). I actually used `.transpose()` accidentally in the middle (changed that and added a note on that).